# Lines changed to dots upon export to SVG

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

The illustrator looks like this
[image]

The exported SVG looks like this [image]

Looking at the SVG syntax, one can see that the lines were changed to dots (row 39-41).

My question is, why is this happening, and how do I get the lines to be exported to the SVG? I have checked that ALL items are exported as a single asset.

The SVG is file is what follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1010 983.95">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        stroke: #231f20;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 10px;
      }

      .cls-1, .cls-3 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #00aeef;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        clip-path: url(#clippath);
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="clippath">
      <rect class="cls-3" x="5" y="9.62" width="700" height="969.33"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
    <g id="main">
      <rect class="cls-1" x="5" y="5" width="700" height="973.95"/>
      <g id="clippingMask">
        <g class="cls-4">
          <g id="fillAmount">
            <path class="cls-2" d="M705,518.06c-87.52,0-87.52,12.47-175.05,12.47s-87.52-12.47-175.05-12.47-87.46,12.47-174.93,12.47-87.49-12.47-174.98-12.47v460.89H705v-460.89Z"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g id="measures">
        <polyline class="cls-1" points="805 5 1005 5 1005 978.95 805 978.95"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1005,491.97h0Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1005,735.46h0Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1005,248.49h0Z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use a different tool that doesn't have this bug or report the bug and wait for a fix.

Comment: I wonder if the lines are actual lines (and not e.g. rectangles or some curves)

Comment: @qrsngky The lines are actually lines from the "line tool". The line itself has only stroke applies to it and thats it.

Comment: @RobertLongson illustrator is industry standard. I am not saying your comment is invalid, but exporting a line should work. I am not sure this is exactly a bug, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing it should work but you don't have a programming question here, you just need to report the bug to Illustrator.

Comment: I have worked with Adobe Illustrator output before, where there are `<line>` tags rather than `<path>` tags for straight lines. Maybe you can change some of the output settings to use `<line>` in order to avoid this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Abobe Illustrator is converting lines to dots.  However, you can fix it by changing lines 39-41 like so:

```
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1005,491.97h-200,0Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1005,735.46h-100,0Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1005,248.49h-100,0Z"/>
```

Comment: The `Z`s are unnecessary

Comment: I did fix it manually, but still it really puzzles me why it is not working. Is it because it is not a closed path?